# mobi site animation stops when scrolls on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, css-animations

I'm trying to make a simple parallax effect for mobile site using javascript.

It works fine when I check from my desktop browser. When I check it from mobile device and scroll using touch on that time the animation freezes. It shows again after releasing the touch screen.

Is there any way to keep animating when I scroll using touch screen?

Well, just any kind of JS animation will freezes up while you scroll through touch screen mobile.

```
lft = 0;
setInterval(function(){  
  lft++;
  $('#my-div').css('margin-left',lft+'px');     
},100);
```

If someone want see the problem in live, have a look here

http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/

It shows great in desktop browser but freezes animation from mobile browser while touched and scrolled.

Thanks

Comment: You should append some code so people can see what you up to.

Comment: Well any kind of animation will freezes while you scroll through touch screen. I've added a sample one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't control how mobile browsers choose to render content. Just like in IE6 when animated gif files would stop animating during scroll, I think the mobile browser is designed to stop animating during scroll.

That being said, I have played with some of the Safari specific effects and had moderate success doing impressive stuff on the iPhone. Also there are libraries out there like "PhoneGap" which allow for you to write native "web applications" for phones.

Other than creating the whole animation from scratch with the express purpose of mobile performance, I don't see a way to simply make that script work.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. But I've found couple of examples for iPhone / Android while it is animating upon swipe. for example if you go here from your phone. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/  then user interface -> Carousel. You will see swipe and animation at the same time. I want to know the trick behind it. Any ideas?

Comment: So, you would probably have to dig into the Sencha Touch script [http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/] they are using. If you can find a non-minified version, look for the "Carousel" method. That will most likely lead you to exactly how they are accomplishing that smooth transition.